# Fix non manifold edges for 3d printing a lego piece

Tags: mesh, geometry, 3d-printing

This is my first ever using Blender and attempting to 3D print. I've cleaned up the piece by deleting edges (Limited Dissolve), intercepting faces (Knife) and deleting some of the non-manifold faces but got to the point that I try some of the solutions I found online and none seem to fix my case. My goal is to 3D print this piece with the best quality/detail possible.

I would like to learn the steps to follow to fix this problem. I have some more piece to clean up and print. Help is appreciated.[image: lego piece]

Here is the [Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NCywgI4poloZOILsfTWV2JEUXqzo1ytY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi, I don't think there is any universal way of fixing any messy mesh. With this simple geometry the best course of action might be to remodel the piece. Especially since you have to consider 3d printing process. You might be able to avoid overhangs and the need for supports if you change the model's inside. What printer are you planning to use?

Comment: A good start would be to look at 3D Printing Tool Box and get an over view of the process of using it  https://youtu.be/0rgrLWFUjlk

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys, I got an Ender 3 S1 Pro. I'm about to give up on my blender skills. lol

Comment: @RickT, I'm ok using the 3D Printing tool.. though it's hard for me to clean up one of those pieces.

Comment: @user1791567, why and what skills exactly are you about to give up on? You said it's the first time you used Blender. Please forgive me for saying, but it seems unlikely, you have a lot of skills to give up on. I would recommend facing it and dedicating time to learn first. Learning 3d modelling is worth it especially for 3d printing. Seems too early to give up. Even in best circumstances it takes at least a couple of months to learn 3d modelling, years to get good at it. Watch tutorials, learn the tools available. You can ask questions about modelling here, if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I recommend you turn on *Overlays > Face Orientation*. It's easier and more pleasing to the eyes, and you can see if *Face Normals* are pointing in the right direction. You have to turn off *X-Ray*.

[image]

You can also try the *Non-Manifold* and *Interior Faces* options under menu *Select* > [`Select All by Trait`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/all_by_trait.html), but be wary that these options don't always work properly so use carefully. Options depend on the *Select Mode* (Vertex or Face Select Mode).

[image]

You can easily see the interiors of your model by selecting the outer face in *Edit Mode* and pressing <kbd>H</kbd> to hide faces. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything. Now you can see some problematic areas.

[image]

Apparently you have interior faces which are non-manifold. Read more about Non-Manifold geometry [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry). Remove those faces.

[image]

Then you have this problematic vertex. It is correctly part of one face but not included in the other face. Remove it by selecting the vertex and pressing <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Vertex*

[image]

Then you have this funny interior face here. These faces should probably be deleted along with 2 bridging edges.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot for your help. @harry-mckenzie